# Using Yarn to install Cypress fails

Tags: cypress, yarnpkg

I tried installing Cypress via Yarn as the directions specify and am getting the following error.

I also notice not all the usual cypress folders were created.

[image: Error]
[image: Only subset of cypress files generated]
What am I doing wrong here?

**Given**

1. `yarn add cypress --dev`
2. `yarn run cypress open`

**Actual**

- Error

**Expect**

- Cypress to run and have some basic examples

Comment: Perhaps you share what's in your `index.js` file?

Comment: Same issue - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/19478

Answer (score 0):

First install the yarn package globally by running  `npm install -g yarn` and restart your terminal.

After you can try with this command:

```
yarn add cypress
```